# App store localized description not show correctly

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

This is the first time I try to localized app store description, so I start with English (which I set as default) and my language which is Thai. I set it up in itune connect web panel before an app update submission. Today my app got approved, but when I looking it in the app store the description isn't translated as I expected. Anybody experinced this kind of problem before ? I don't know what I do wrong it should be an easy process.
Here is my test environment:

- I use Thai itune account.
- I set my language in iphone setting to Thai and relaunch the app store (kill it from task manager and open it
  again).
- I set my localized to Thai.
  But all this don't seem to work I still see it in English.

Even description on the web is not showing Thai language
English link: http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/tiny-thai-news-reader-lite/id509771273?mt=8
Thai link: http://itunes.apple.com/th/app/tiny-thai-news-reader-lite/id509771273?mt=8
(Now I hot fix by adding Thai description above English description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I check the app store again and the description is showing correctly, I guess it may take some time before everything set up properly. Itune connect and app store process remain mystery to me.

Comment: I do not think it is showing correctly.